# SG-1 Torment of Tantalus: The book and universal language

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1, continuity

Did Jackson or anyone else ever specifically ask the Asgard, Nox, etc. about what was inside the "book", the "atomic language", etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was not explicitly referenced in any of the aired episodes, so I'd say "no", however, as we see in the episode "Unending", the Asgard *do* give their complete database to SG-1/The Tau'ri/the people of Earth, and it could reasonably be presumed that most of the book at Heliopolis was a part of that.

Comment: Thanks, I've been re-watching the series and that question among many others came to mind.

Comment: Thor said the Asgard were giving the Tau'ri *their* knowledge. This can be interpreted as "only original Asgard knowledge" or "everything from the 4 species alliance". However, if the latter were the case, why didn't Sam just learn to construct a stargate and send themselves and all the Asgard equipment and data through it before the time-dilated ship was destroyed?